# After installing MakeGood plugin, eclipse won't start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, phpunit

I want to run PHPUnit tests inside Eclipse PDT - and the MakeGood plugin sounded great. I'm having problems with the installation though.

First, I tried installing it via "Install new software" - it seemed to install properly, and then asked me to restart eclipse. But eclipse would not restart. After waiting a while, I tried to restart eclipse, but the splash screen comes on for 2 seconds and then disappears. I couldn't open eclipse at all. I read about deleting the .snap files, but I didn't have any.

I ended up deleting eclipse and installing it fresh. I turned off the User Account Control, at least for now, because I read that might cause issues. Anyways, I tried instaling Makegood again on a fresh new eclipse in a fresh new workspace - does the same thing... installs, and fails to restart. And when you try to restart manually, it dies.

Here is a portion of the error log... Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-06-24 04:19:18.443
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.osgi.framework.Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)I
    at com.piece_framework.makegood.aspect.PDTVersion.<init>(PDTVersion.java:46)
    at com.piece_framework.makegood.aspect.PDTVersion.getInstance(PDTVersion.java:57)
    at com.piece_framework.makegood.aspect.PDTVersionSourceProvider.getCurrentState(PDTVersionSourceProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.ExpressionAuthority.addSourceProvider(ExpressionAuthority.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.addSourceProvider(EvaluationService.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$57.run(Workbench.java:2342)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.startSourceProviders(Workbench.java:2336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$18(Workbench.java:2321)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$30.runWithException(Workbench.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MakeGood 2.3.0, Eclipse 3.7 or greater is needed to work.

Comment: i updated eclipse (needed to do a fresh install), and now it's working, thanks